# How is css specificity determined for elements with the same selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I have two styles affecting the same element (`myDiv`) from different stylesheets.

**Stylesheet1.css**

```
.myDiv{
  background-color:#000;
}
```

**Stylesheet2.css**

```
.myDiv{
  background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Neither style is more specific than the other, and neither have `!important` appended.

However I'm finding that the same css consistently gives priority to *Stylesheet1.css* on one server, but *Stylesheet2.css* on another! Can anyone suggest why that would be?

(Due to business reasons I don't want to simply *fix* it- I just want to understand why it is behaving that way.)

Comment: depends on the order they are included

Comment: @Pete You mean like the position the reference appears in the html?

Comment: The order of the rule - the one that comes last will take precendence

Comment: CSS goes from top to bottom. If you had the two styles in the same stylesheet, the second style would overwrite the other . If you have 2 stylesheets with the same selector, the style from the one you import second, that's the one that will overwrite the first.

Comment: Thanks guys. I know it seems simple now but I could not figure that out.